# JDBC driver connection problems (sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver)

Tags: java, sql-server, dsn, jdbc-odbc

I'm having some issues with the connection with Java and SQL 2008 Express. I'm using `sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver` driver for the connections and have created my dsn through the admin tools and this is the code I'm using:

```
import java.sql.*;

public class JdbcFirstTry 
{
     public static void main(String args[]) throws SQLException
     {

         try {
                Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");

                Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:movie_archive_DSN");
                System.out.print("you made connection");
          }
          catch (Exception e)
          {
             e.printStackTrace();
          }
    }
}
```

This is the error I'm getting:

> Data source name not found and no default driver specified

Can anyone offer advice on how to fix this error? Also tcp/ip is enabled and port set to 1433.

I have also tried this way as well but kept getting a time out error:

```
 Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");

      String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://WALSER:1433;databaseName=MYSQLDATABASE;user=walser/kyle;password=brenna1020;";

      Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);
```

and the error is:

> The TCP/IP connection to the host WALSER, port 1433 has failed. Error:
>   "Connection refused: connect. Verify the connection properties. Make
>   sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and
>   accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP
>   connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.".

Comment: it's clear as it says, try to check the names are equal in OS and in code

Comment: all names are spelled correctly. is there anything else it could be?

Comment: could you ping the data source by the OS directly? check it. btw, why don't you connect directly to the SQL Server? ODBC eats your performance buddy, just enable the [SQL Authentication](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/616114/SQL-Server-T-SQL-Tips-Tricks#xp_regeditwrite) , download the driver, and have a direct connection :)

Comment: Would you still need the dsn for the username and pswd to work?

Comment: no buddy, you need to set the user and pass with dns binding(in OS), it doesn't required to specify again in Java applicaiotn. please check every thing, check databse is running, check os able to ping the database (during dns binding), check ds names are same, I know there is just a simple problem there :)

Comment: ive set user name and password in the dsn binding, created a separate login account for sql and gave it sysadmin permissions, created a separate rule in the firewall for it to have access just in case there was something going on with the default port, downloaded the driver sqljdbc4.jar and added to the library and still getting and error with the port

Comment: The TCP/IP connection to the host WALSER, port 1433 has failed.

Comment: so it means your SQL server doesn't support the TCP protocol, so let me explain it with an answer

Answer (score 0):

To resolve no default driver, you need to specify type of database specific driver, e.g.

1. `oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver` for Oracle
2. `com;sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybDataSource` for sybase

Secondly please add username and password in connection call.

Answer (score 0):

as you said, your protocol (TCP) is disable, so let activate it with some code :)
source from [codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/616114/SQL-Server-T-SQL-Tips-Tricks#xp_regeditwrite)

```
--step 1: creating a login (mandatory)
create login login_to_system_after_injection with password='Thank$SQL4Registry@ccess';
GO
--step 2: enabling both windows/SQL Authentication mode
/*some server specific configurations are not stored in system (SQL)*/
--set the value to 1 for disabling the SQL Authentication Mode after . . .
exec xp_regwrite N'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE', N'Software\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\MSSQLServer', N'LoginMode', REG_DWORD, 2;
--step 3:getting the server instance name
declare @spath nvarchar(256);
--SQL SERVER V100 path, use SQL9 for V90
exec master..xp_regread N'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE',
                 N'Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\Instance Names\SQL' ,N'SQL10',@spath output,no_output 
--step 4:preparing registry path
declare @insRegPath nvarchar(1024)=N'Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\' + 
                                      @spath + '\MSSQLServer\SuperSocketNetLib\Tcp';
--step 5:enabling tcp protocol
exec xp_regwrite N'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE', @insRegPath, N'Enabled', REG_DWORD, 1 --generally tries to enable all addresses. NOT Recommended
--step 6:enabling remote access
--EXEC sys.sp_configure N'remote access', 1
GO
RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE --reconfigure is required!
GO
--step 7:a system restart is required in order to enabling remote access.
--step 7.1:shutting down the server
shutdown
--After this command you need to start the server implicitly yourself.
--or just configure the Agent in order to start the server at any shutdown or failure
```

you need a server reastart after running the above code, also you need sysadmin rule too :)

if the above code doesn't work so go to start -> all programs -> Microsoft SQL server 2008 -> configuration tools -> SQL server configuration manager

then select the "SQL Server network configuration" from the left pane, and select the desired instance, then enable the TCP/IP from the right pane, and restart the server

then in Java application, you need to change the class name and connection string
just after downloading the library, add it to the class path and now your code will be like this

```
public class JdbcFirstTry 
    {
      public static void main(String args[]) throws SQLException
     {

         try {
                Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");

                Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=DatabaseName;integratedSecurity=true;");
                System.out.print("you made connection");
          }
          catch (Exception e)
          {

             e.printStackTrace();
         }

     }

    }
```

in above integratedSecurity=true means uses the windows account to connect, but simple you would add the username and password with connection string as `user=MyUserName;password=*****`

finally, have a try and inform me dude about the result, hope you get it run :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows 7 64 bit Go to

C:\Windows\SysWOW64
and search for odbcad32.exe

from there you get ODBC data source administrator 
and create the dsn